# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS very slow downloading

Tags: 22.04, network-manager, internet

i have Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS jammy and i use wired connection internet.
My problem is the download is to slow with a very slow speed downloading.My internet connection is fine and work perfect with speed to other devices in the some network .
For example if i want to download a file 2 gb in my computer i need 4 hours to downloading but in other devices i need 7 minutes.I try many things but without success,any idea how to fix it ?

here my settings :

sudo lshw -C network :

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
       logical name: enp13s0
       version: 05
       serial: d8:5e:d3:e2:42:15
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8125 driverversion=9.011.00-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.100.16 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:35 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:80000000-8000ffff memory:80010000-80013fff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0e:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=mt7921e latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf irq:164 memory:fcf0300000-fcf03fffff memory:80100000-80107fff
```

sudo lspci :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14d8
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14da
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14db
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14da
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14db
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14da
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14da
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14da
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14dd
00:08.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14dd
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 71)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f4 (rev 01)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
03:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
03:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
03:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
03:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
03:08.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
03:0c.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
03:0d.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
09:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f4 (rev 01)
0a:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
0a:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
0a:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
0a:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
0a:08.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
0a:0c.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
0a:0d.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
0d:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 05)
0e:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 0616
10:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f7 (rev 01)
11:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f6 (rev 01)
12:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f7 (rev 01)
13:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f6 (rev 01)
14:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 164e (rev c1)
14:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1640
14:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] VanGogh PSP/CCP
14:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b6
14:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b7
14:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
15:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b8
```

ip link :

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp13s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:5e:d3:e2:42:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

ethtool enp13s0 :

```
Settings for enp13s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
                            2500baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                         1000baseT/Full
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    MDI-X: Unknown
netlink error: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

speedtest-cli :

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from HCN - Hellenic Cable Networks (xx.xx.xxx.xxx)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by DATACOM JV (Skopje) [197.18 km]: 83.45 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 6.46 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
```

ping -c 10 8.8.8.8 :

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=112 time=54.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=112 time=53.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=112 time=53.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=112 time=53.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=112 time=54.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=112 time=54.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=112 time=53.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=112 time=54.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=112 time=52.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=10 ttl=112 time=53.2 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9015ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 52.847/53.682/54.154/0.405 ms
```

nmcli dev show enp13s0 :

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp13s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         D8:5E:D3:E2:42:15
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                        xxx.xxx.xxx.16/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                           xxx.xxx.xxx.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh =xxx.xxx.xxx.1, mt = 0
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst =xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::da5e:d3ff:fee2:4215/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
```

sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved :

```
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-03-31 02:11:01 EEST; 1h 34min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
   Main PID: 4366 (systemd-resolve)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 37328)
     Memory: 4.4M
        CPU: 41ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
             └─4366 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

Μusername-mystyme systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
username-mystyme systemd-resolved[4366]: Positive Trust Anchors:
username-mystyme systemd-resolved[4366]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
username-mystyme systemd-resolved[4366]: Negative trust anchors: home.arpa 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-add>
username-mystyme systemd-resolved[4366]: Using system hostname 'username-mystyme'.
username-mystyme systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
```

nmcli connection show :

```
enp13s0              7115fd2f-9814-4ec8-ab83-9fc5a9b990c1  ethernet  enp13s0 
enp13s0              8485cf8e-db53-4537-8178-4eafd5083e06  ethernet  --      
enp13s0              f0472113-cd46-490f-b72e-06673fee6df2  ethernet  --      
Ενσύρματη σύνδεση 1  5e8d5574-99ee-3252-bb27-a32c833241df  ethernet  --
```

Comment: Might want to see:  https://www.linux.org/threads/2-5gb-s-nic-at-1gb-s-speed-jeremyy44.37296/ where you can try changing the speed manually for the card via `sudo ethtool -s enp13s0 speed 2500 duplex full autoneg on`

Comment: Try "sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager"

Comment: @Terrance i tried and not fix it .

Comment: @peter yes i tried some problem